# Blackberry Bold 9900 on Rogers mobile network redirects google.com to google.ca

Tags: blackberry, redirect

A Blackberry Java app question..

It seems that Blackberry Bold 9900 on Rogers mobile network redirects google.com to google.ca, which messes my app .. I tried to contact Rogers but they referred me to RIM customer support :)

So for example, HTTP request to http://www.google.com/accounts/.. is redirected to http://www.google.ca/accounts/SetSID..

Appreciate any idea

Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a problem with your application or your provider - the problem is (probably) the result of two things:

1. BlackBerry internet traffic passing through BES/BIS servers which seem to be located in Canada in this case
2. Google using your IP address to figure out where in the world you are and redirecting you to the local Google domain

Google has a no-redirection URL `http://www.google.com/ncr` which will take you to the .com page no matter where you are. I'm not sure but it's quite possible that if you visit that page and then use the cookies that you're given, you should be able to force all responses from Google to stay on the .com domain.